# How to convert xml url calendar into ical (ics) in order to import it and sync it with google Calendar (Outlook and others)

Tags: xml, calendar, google-calendar-api, icalendar

I want to link and import the calendar of my organisation to Google Calendar (and many other calendar platforms) with a regular update. But unfortunately, my url calendar is in xml format instead of ics:

https://exnet.3il.fr/rp/TousCom/Emploi%20du%20temps/I1%20Groupe%201.xml (password needed from the user)

Please do you know where I can convert my link online into ics/ical  and link it with google Calendar with a regular update ?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Someone made a Perl script to convert xml calendars to ICS called [grindstone2ics.txt](https://www.muchtall.com/content/grindstone2ics.txt). The instructions for using this script is found in [this guide](https://www.muchtall.com/2012/10/24/exportimport-grindstone-xml-to-googleicalics/). When you're successful converting it to ICS, you can now [import it in your Google Calendar](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37100?hl=en).